# Outlook add-in On send feature not calling function

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I've been testing Outlook add-in On-send feature on Chromium Edge. But for some reason it never calls the function validateBody.

command.js

```
let mailboxItem;
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
      mailboxItem = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    };
    // Determine whether the body contains a specific set of blocked words. If it contains the blocked words, block email from being sent. Otherwise allow sending.
    // <param name="asyncResult">ItemSend event passed from the calling function.</param>
    async function checkBodyOnlyOnSendCallBack(asyncResult) {
      const listOfBlockedWords = new Array("dammit", "porra", "caralho");
      const wordExpression = listOfBlockedWords.join("|");
    
      // \b to perform a "whole words only" search using a regular expression in the form of \bword\b.
      // i to perform case-insensitive search.
      const regexCheck = new RegExp("\\b(" + wordExpression + ")\\b", "i");
      const checkBody = regexCheck.test(asyncResult.value);
    
      if (checkBody) {
        mailboxItem.notificationMessages.addAsync("NoSend", {
          type: "errorMessage",
          message: "Blocked words have been found in the body of this email. Please remove them.",
        });
        // Block send.
        asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: false });
      }
    
      // Allow send.
      asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: true });
    }
    // Entry point for Contoso Message Body Checker add-in before send is allowed.
    // <param name="event">ItemSend event is automatically passed by on-send code to the function specified in the manifest.</param>
    function validateBody(event) {
      mailboxItem.body.getAsync("html", { asyncContext: event }, checkBodyOnlyOnSendCallBack);
    }
```

manifest.xml

```
    <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />
                <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
                  <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="validateBody" />
                </ExtensionPoint>
...
<bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        </bt:Urls>
```

Office.initialize is always called but never validateBody. But consequense I just get the message:
We're sorry, we couldn't access Test. Make sure you have a network connection. If the problem continues, please try again later. The add-in Test has prevented this item from being sent.

How can I fix this issue?

Edit: This the error message on Outlook windows
[image: Outlook windows]

Outlook version:
Microsoft® Outlook® 2019 MSO (16.0.14326.20164) 64-bit
This the error message on Outlook web
[image: Outlook web]

Comment: Do you have any problems with running a sample add-in mentioned in the post?

Comment: To be honest. The result is the same from the one I did. Do the On send add-in needs some type of special configuration? Because I install the same way I did with the other that I did is the same. I install the Add-in through manifest but when I try to send the message it repeats the same behavior

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev I believe I understand my error I'm using my free outlook account live.com as testing environment so I can't use On send because my email does not allowed to do so right?

Comment: What Outlook client are you using (Mac, Win32, OWA)? The list of supported clients and platforms for OnSend can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows#supported-clients-and-platforms

Comment: I'm using OWA. I tried on windows but again I got a error but a different one: ... coundn't complete

Comment: Are you testing using the sample add-in? If the sample add-in is not working, your version of Outlook might not be supported. What build of Outlook are you using and what version of Exchange? Could you add more details about the error you are seeing on Windows Outlook?

Comment: I edit the question with info you requested

Comment: Could you confirm if you're facing similar issue with the sample addin in documentation? Also, another thing to try would be to host the application on a webserver and then giving it a try- does this work with your addin and the sample addin. You say that Office.initialize is always called, could you share how you tested that the initialize function is being called. Another thing to try in the interim is to have the validateBody function call do something plain and simple like stamp a notificationMessage/change the subject of the email to confirm if that simple snippet works.

Comment: Well, I use vscode to start the server on https://localhost:3000. After I take the manifest and add it on the platform that I need to test it web or desktop.

Comment: For the error in OWA, since the add-in couldn't be accessed, could you try opening the html function file directly in the same browser to see if an error is returned?

Answer (score 0):

> We're sorry, we couldn't access Test. Make sure you have a network connection. If the problem continues, please try again later. The add-in Test has prevented this item from being sent.

That is a good indicator that OfficeJS runtime can't locate the function specified in the manifest file. Make sure the web app is running on the specified in the manifest URL and the function is publicly accessible.

By default if the callback is not located (couldn't reach the function) the send operation is blocked and the notification message is shown to users.

I'd suggest playing with [the sample project available on GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send) before changing anything in the add-in or create your own and modify it.